# mysql sub_string replace?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible in mysql to replace the first character of a cell with something else?

eg I have

64123
64340
64067
0104
0240
0456

I need to replace all the **starting** 0's with 64

how could I do this?

Comment: Do you mean replace the first `0` only if it is the first char?

Comment: That would be correct, I know I can use Replace() to replace ALL zero's but how do I do only the first zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE action_4_members
SET mobile = CONCAT('64', SUBSTRING(mobile,2))
WHERE SUBSTRING(mobile,1,1) = '0'
```

Comment: I have attempted `UPDATE action_4_members SET mobile = (IF SUBSTRING(mobile,0,1) == "0" THEN CONCAT("64", SUBSTRING(mobile,1)) ELSE mobile);` but I get syntax error  near 'SUBSTRING(mobile,0,1) == "0" THEN CONCAT("64", SUBSTRING(mobile,1)) ELSE mobile)'

Comment: In an UPDATE statement you don't need the IF this should be done in the WHERE clause. I adjusted the code.

Comment: My bad, Now I have tried `UPDATE action_4_members SET `mobile` = CONCAT("64", SUBSTRING(`mobile`,1)) WHERE SUBSTRING(`mobile`,0,1) = '0';` But its not updating any rows.

Comment: ah fixed it, had to use 0 instead of '0'